# How to pass the $event to the onEnter function of angular ui router state

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angular-ui-router

I have a question, maybe a stupid one, I am using `ui-router` state to open a modal just like explained [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-open-a-dialogmodal-at-a-certain-state), except the part the modal is not ui-bootstrap's it is angular-material's [`$mdDialog`](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.dialog). As some of you know that the $mdDialog slides in from the element clicked not from top-to-center like bootstrap-modal. Right now it is fading in no sliding, I would like to slide the modal from the element. 
I did created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/salalaslam/f30wesj3/) for this purpose. 
Here is the code

```
var app = angular
  .module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngAria', 'ngMaterial', 'ui.router'])

.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state("campaigns", {
        url: "/campaigns",
        abstract: true
      })
      .state("campaigns.add", {
        url: "/add",
        onEnter: function($mdDialog) {
          var ev = null; // this should be the $event 
          $mdDialog.show(
            $mdDialog.alert()
            .parent(angular.element(document.body))
            .title('This is an alert title')
            .content('You can specify some description text in here.')
            .ariaLabel('Alert Dialog Demo')
            .ok('Got it!')
            .targetEvent(ev)
          );
        }
      });
  }])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {

  });
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController"><a ui-sref="campaigns.add">add campaign</a></div>
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/32685753/202913 , demo at http://jsfiddle.net/f30wesj3/2/